# how to update latest post sqlite3?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sql-update, sql-order-by

I need to update the latest entry in the database. While the query works correctly in the DB browser, it doesn't work in code. Please tell me what's the matter?

```
class MySQL:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(file_db, check_same_thread=False)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        self.add_bd()     
    def update_sell_price(self, sell_price):
        with self.connection:
            self.cursor.execute(
                f'UPDATE Deals SET sell_price={sell_price}  ORDER BY deal_id DESC LIMIT 1')
```

Gives an error message: sqlite3.OperationalError: near "ORDER": syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [LIMIT and ORDER BY Clauses](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html#optional_limit_and_order_by_clauses) are available in the `UPDATE` statement only if SQLite is built with the [SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT](https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_update_delete_limit) compile-time option, which I suspect is not what you have in the version that you work with.

Instead use a scalar subquery to get the max `deal_id`:

```
sql = """
  UPDATE Deals 
  SET sell_price = ?
  WHERE deal_id = (SELECT MAX(deal_id) FROM Deals)
"""
self.cursor.execute(sql, (sell_price,))
```